# Want to change the backgroung color (or put the text on bold) to the current VAADIN menu bar item selection

Tags: java, css, vaadin8

I want to put a different color when my menu item has been selected. 
My menu is : 
[image]

For that, the code is :

```
  /**
     * Create a Vertical Menu with the Home page and Actions page
     */
    public MenuBar createMenu() {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.addItem(StringConstants.MENU_HOMEPAGE_LABEL, VaadinIcons.HOME, createCommandHomepage());
        menuBar.addItem(StringConstants.MENU_ACTIONS_LABEL, VaadinIcons.TABLE, createCommandActions());
        menuBar.addItem(StringConstants.MENU_LOG_OUT_LABEL, VaadinIcons.SIGN_OUT, createCommandLogOut());
        return menuBar;
    }

    /**
     * Create the command when the Home page has been selected in the menu
     */
    private Command createCommandHomepage() {
        return new Command() {
            @Override
            public void menuSelected(final MenuBar.MenuItem selectedItem) {
                selectedItem.setStyleName("caption");
                UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo(StringConstants.HOMEPAGE_VIEW_NAME);
            }
        };
    }
    /**
     * Same for the Action and Log out - it's not important to show the code here
     */
```

So I tried to put the current selection in bold (I tried to change the background too).

So My scss code was :

```
.v-menubar-menuitem-selected{
          font-weight: bold;
    }

    .caption {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

And this is not working at all. 
However :

```
.v-menubar-menuitem-caption{
          font-weight: bold;
    }
```

is working, but it will put all captions in bold, not just the current selection.

I don't know what I did wrong.

**EDIT**: I compile the vaadin theme :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, I run a maven clean package to be sure that I build the theme.

EDIT 2 : Vaadin version from pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Vaadin version?

Comment: @avix vaadin version is 8. I used maven so the exact version is : 8.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working. But, I think **it's not the better one.** So, please, provide a better answer.

I use the session to save the menu level :

```
String menuTabSelected =(String)VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("menuState");
MenuBar barmenu = new MenuBar();
barmenu.addStyleName("mybarmenu");
layout.addComponent(barmenu);

String homepageStyle = menuTabSelected == null || menuTabSelected.equals(StringConstants.MENU_HOMEPAGE_LABEL) ? "highlight" : null;

barmenu.addItem(StringConstants.MENU_HOMEPAGE_LABEL, VaadinIcons.HOME, createCommandHomepage()).setStyleName(homepageStyle);


private Command createCommandHomepage() {
    return new Command() {
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(final MenuItem selectedItem) {

            VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("menuState", selectedItem.getText());

            UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo(StringConstants.HOMEPAGE_VIEW_NAME);
        }
    };
}
```

In mytheme.scss :

```
.mybarmenu .v-menubar-menuitem-highlight {
    background: #dedede;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Vaadin 8 Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-menubar.html):

> ...beware that the selected style for menu items, that is,
>   `v-menubar-menuitem-selected`, is reserved for mouse-hover indication.

Try this:

```
.myTheme .v-menubar-menuitem-highlight {
    background: #000040;
}
```

and in code:

```
menuBar.addStyleName("myTheme");
```

Also remember to clear cache from your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this before and it's not working. I used it also like "selectedItem.setStyleName"highlight" without success. I've clear my cache

Comment: Have you tried without adding style to `selectedItem`? Just with setting style of `menuBar`

Comment: Yes, Exactly like you wrote. I tried to build the theme two times and clear my cache two times too. That should works, i don't know why it's not working...